# Google Funding Choices API Implementation

Tags: fundingchoices

I'm struggling with Funding Choices Javascript API.
The documentation is terrible and confusing.

I'm trying to get EU consent from users before loading third-party header bidding ads.

It says in the documentation(https://support.google.com/fundingchoices/answer/9182225?hl=en) I need to add Funding Choices tag but there is no Deployment link in Funding Choices website.I'm not directly using DFP(Google Ad Manager) but there is nothing in there as well.

So how come I can find this tags and use the API.
If anyone has accomplished a similar thing, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks